# AngularJS Slightly Advanced Validation / Bootstrap3 Style

Tags: validation, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am in the process of learning AngularJS, still at the most basic stages of form validation. I followed the [official tutorial here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms), and managed to get the validation working like they have, where if input is invalid, the background changes colour.

[image: Bootstrap Style Form]

That is all nice and counts as an important step in my learning, but how do I move a little further and have the validation add / remove CSS classes required by Bootstrap to show visual cues?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form novalidate class="css-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.fname" required >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.lname" required >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" required >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" required >
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="emailpref">Want annoying emails?</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="user.emailpref" required>
      <option value="Null">Please Select</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In the [Bootstrap3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), it says that if I need to show a valid state, I must add a CSS class of `has-success` like so:

```
<div class="form-group has-success">
    <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.fname" required >
</div>
```

How can I get my AngularJS validation to do that? At the moment, my AngularJS is as follows:

```
function UserCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};
    $scope.user   = { fname: "J", lname: "Watson", password: "test", email: "j.watson@world.com", emailpref: "Yes" };

    $scope.update = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
    };

    $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.reset();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I simplify form validation in angularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022180/how-can-i-simplify-form-validation-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add dynamic classes based on field validation you need to do two things

Give your form a `name`

```
 `<form novalidate class="css-form" name="form1">`
```

Give each input field a `name` too. You can then use expression to determine state of error of a field

```
<div class="form-group has-success" ng-class="{'has-success':form1.fname.$invalid}">
    <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.fname" required name="fname">
</div>
```

Please go through the form guide http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms for more details.

Comment: can you please explain what this `ng-class="{'has-success':form1.fname.$invalid}` does? If I had to guess, I'd say it is saying add a class of `has-success` when the `fname` field is invalid! And that doesn't make sense to me!

Comment: By the way, I did read that link you provided, what you are doing is not mentioned on there :(

Comment: Sorry, i reversed the condition, but the idea remains the same. The documentation gives similar example. Search for expression usage liek `form.uEmail.$dirty`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular-validator](https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator).

Disclaimer: I am the author of angular-validator