# Reference angular ng-form from controller

Tags: angularjs

How can I reference the ng-form object from within my controller?

I have

```
<ng-form name="myForm">
</ng-form>
```

This code on the HTML page works fine

```
 {{myForm.$valid}}
```

returning true or false as the case may be.

But what I want is to check the status of the form from within a funciton in the controller, for example before posting the data or retrieving data.

I have tried

```
$scope.myForm.$valid
```

but this doesn't exist. Neither is there any reference to the `myForm` object in the `$scope` itself.

The `ng-form` is used within an `ng-repeat`, all of which is within a normal HTML form object which is why it is being used.

As I said, the `myForm.$invalid` is used to control the display/enabled controls within that form on the HTML page just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: In what function to you want to use it? Is it ngClick, or ngSubmit function?

Comment: The answer to this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022180/how-can-i-simplify-form-validation-in-angularjs. It seems that you can use $valid and $invalid on elements of a form rather than the whole form.

Comment: possible duplicate. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22965461/2460773

Comment: @dfsq - It is not used in any of those functions, but rather in another $scope function such as $scope.getAdditionalData

Comment: @camden_kid - Yes I can already control the submit button by using ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" as mentioned.

Comment: You should use `$scope.myForm.$valid`. In your case you are doing something wrong, because `myForm` object will be available in the scope. Make sure you are checking correct $scope.

Comment: @Nitsan Baleli - No I don't think it's anything like that. I am specifically referencing the ng-form attribute, not the html form tag.

Comment: @dfsq - I have already tried that. But the $scope.myForm is undefined. There is only 1 scope

Comment: Well I guess I know your problem. Can you post complete HTML with ngRepeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one approach to check if a form is valid upon submitting will be to pass the `myForm.$valid` into the submit function:

```
<ng-form name="myForm" ng-submit="test(myForm.$valid, obj)">
  <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="obj.user" required>
  <input type="submit" ng-click="test(myForm.$valid, obj)" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">
</ng-form>
```

and the test function:

```
$scope.test = function($valid, obj) {
  if (!$valid) return;
  console.log(obj);
}
```

**[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzx7pWA4Hbz4Liga3hmE?p=preview)**

Comment: That looks like it will do what I want but only on a submit? Can the state (and specifically the myForm.$error object not be accessed without posting it back as shown?

Comment: actually if you look at this plnkr, the function can access the myForm object from the controller: http://plnkr.co/edit/KEa5Nq3aynAETKS86YMy?p=preview

Comment: correct, that does work for a single ng-form but not in a ng-repeat. See the fork of your fiddle as an example. http://plnkr.co/edit/d7WEoX0h37MziGfnJtMS?p=preview
I would like to be able to access it like you have shown but in the form $scope.myForm[2] perhaps?

Comment: @DeclanMcD in this case, when ng-repeat creates a new scope for each form, you're better to pass the form to the function and printing it. http://plnkr.co/edit/ONhN26xik2M2HcBZQa6z?p=preview