# AngularJs Input textbox allow only greater than zero value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am trying validate the textbox allow only integer number and greater than zero values.

Here I attached my code.

Html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  NUMBER ONLY <input type="text" allow-pattern="\d" />

</body>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.directive('allowPattern', [allowPatternDirective]);

function allowPatternDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
                    var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode; // I safely get the 
                    if (!keyCodeChar.match(new RegExp(attrs.allowPattern, "i"))) {
            event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }          
                });
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Also I tried like this bellow:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  NUMBER ONLY <input type="text" allow-pattern="^[1-9][0-9]*$" />

</body>
```

But its not working.

Check jsfiddle link: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23591/)

Comment: why a separate directive? you may use `ng-pattern`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular validate input type="number"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395188/angular-validate-input-type-number)

Comment: @Gianmarco - input type="number" is not suitable for my case, because the textbox text or number option based on another dropdown select option. Its possible to do in my example?

Comment: did you tried to print `keyCodeChar` var?

Comment: @AvinashRaj - ng-pattern is validate after form submit, I expect allow only greater than 0 values.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - I am using this function many places. Please suggest some way. I will follow

Comment: @RSKMR pls post the code related to `keyCodeChar`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - your code is not allowing 0 values. eg - 10 not allow to enter

Comment: your directive checks for each char enetered on the text box.. So that it won't accept 0. Make the directive to consider all the entered chars instead of the last entered char.

Comment: Your fiddle contains missprints. Your directive logic is bad - user can copy-paste to input as well as drag text. Imho you should either use html5 input type="number" or allow all characters to input. (just show error if not a number)

Comment: @AvinashRaj -  http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23605/  here i unable to enter round of 10 values.. eg . 10,20

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - yes, now only I thinking if user copy or drag possibilities.

Comment: i would go with smth simple like this http://plnkr.co/edit/0XOLzIcdTAMS8bn8lqjK?p=preview

Comment: @PetrAveryanov - Its not validating greater than zero values. your code accept 0 also. I expect output greater than zero.

Comment: @RSKMR: Then use a lookahead: [`$scope.pattern = '(?!0+$)\\d+';`](http://plnkr.co/edit/GQN59gPqUT9WN5BWKdOL?p=preview)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew u forget to add anchors.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: When you pass the pattern as string in angular, the pattern is anchored automatically. [*If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in `^` and `$` characters.*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I read the docs :)

Comment: Espcially when my kids go to bed. I need more sleep.

Comment: It seems updated fiddle of OP working fine...http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/23605/

Comment: @KhalidHussain - I checked your example - I unable to enter round of 10 values.. eg . 10,20

Comment: @RSKMR: what do you mean by *thanks to all*? Is the version with lookahead working for you? I mean, your fiddle does not work because you check each input char individually with the `^[1-9][0-9]*$` regex. You need to check the whole string.

Comment: I said thanks for we validating only for input enter. possible for  copy/paste/drag the text values.  Can you help for this how can I check whole string.

Comment: try this 

<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[1-9]\d*$/" />

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [angular form validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) and also use [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

Here is the link to [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/rezbEK)

Controller snippet :

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.onlyNumbers = /^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/;
})
```

View :

```
<div ng-app="app">
<br />
<br />
<div class="col-md-2" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form name="myForm1">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':myForm1.number1.$invalid}">
    <label for="">Following validation happens as the user entrs a value.</label>
    <input class="form-control" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" ng-model="value1" name="number1"/> Valid? {{myForm1.number1.$valid}}
  </div>
</form>
<form name="myForm2">
  <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error':myForm2.number2.$invalid}">
    <label for="">Following validation happens after blur </label>
    <input class="form-control" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" ng-model="value2" name="number2" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}"/> Valid? {{myForm2.number2.$valid}}
  </div>
</form>
```

For more on how you can better this process through controllers refer  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022180/how-can-i-simplify-form-validation)